# Check special character in string?

Tags: python

i need to check existing of Character `(*,&,$)` in Given String using python command such as given below?

Eg: `stringexample='mystri$ng&*'`

check stringexample contains any special symbols like *,&,$ then return true?
shall i try with string method  `__contains__()`

Comment: what did you try until now? what did you get with the methods you already tried that didn't work as you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> stringexample = 'mystri$ng&'
>>> '*' in stringexample
False
>>> '$' in stringexample
True
>>> '&' in stringexample
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(c in stringexample for c in '*$&'):
    ...
```

or

```
if not set('*&$').isdisjoint(stringexample):
    ...
```