# Return all numbers that contain 5

Tags: python

I am trying to return all the digits that contain a 5 including the starting and ending values. I created a string list with all the numbers. However, I am confused as to how I can get the values and add them to a new list.
For example, giveMeFive(42, 75) would return the list [45, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56,
57, 58, 59, 65, 75]

```
def giveMeFive():
    num1 = int(input("Whats the first number?"))
    num2 = int(input("Whats the second number?"))
    lst = str(list(range(num1, num2 + 1)))
    print(lst.find("5"))
    newLst = []
    for x in lst:
        if(lst(x) == "5"):
            #stuck
```

Comment: Please share an example with inputs and an expected return value.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many different questions. Search for "python in" and "python append list".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check special character in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884958/check-special-character-in-string)

Comment: BTW, being extremely naïve, this is not an optimal algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you are doing:

```
lst = str(list(range(num1, num2 + 1)))
```

which is converting your list to string, and then you are iterating over the string. Instead your code should be like:

```
lst = list(range(num1, num2 + 1))  # No need to type-cast it to string.
                                   # Infact you don't even need `list` here.
newLst = []
for x in lst:
    #          v type-cast your number to string
    if "5" in str(x):  # check "5" is present in your number string
         newLst.append(x)  # append your number to the list
```

---

Better way to achieve this is via a *list comprehension* expression. For example:

```
>>> number1 = 5
>>> number2 = 31

>>> [i for i in range(number1, number2+1) if "5" in str(i)]
[5, 15, 25]
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
num1 = int(input("Input no 1"))
num2 = int(input("Input no 2"))

lst = map(str, range(num1, num2+1))
#         ^ convert list of numbers to list of "number strings"

List5 = []
for i in lst:
    if "5" in i:
        List5.append(i)
```

Comment: I added an alternative version of the code which will work for the OP. @Kieron Please take a look at it. And, welcome to SO :)

Comment: Thanks @MoinuddinQuadri , this is why you have 20k rep, and i only have 31 :)
Might have to add a else: statement just to annoy you / satisfy my bad habit though :P